# iOS rewriting image file at specific path shows old image

Tags: ios, file, swift, uiimage, url-rewriting

In my iOS app written with swift I set the image from local file on UIImageView with following code: 
`profileImageView.image =  UIImage(named: documentsDirectory[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("myImage.jpeg"))` 
and that works just fine. At some stage (in my case another ViewController) I have to rewrite the file content by either deleting the existing file first and then writing new file to that directory or by moving new file to existing directory. After the file is rewritten the image view keep showing the old image even if I reset its image with the same method as mention above.If I close the app then reopen it the new image is shown.I know that this is probably a cache issue and my question is how to clear cache related to specific file and show new image directly?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @LyndseyScott the problem was with UIImage.imageNamed as David described in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a couple of different problems, the biggest of which is that UIImage.imageNamed specifically caches the image read, so changing the underlying file won't result in the new image being used.  The other (related) issue is that imageNamed is primarily intended to load static images out of the application bundle.

Switch to using `UIImage(contentsOfFile:...)` and make sure you're reloading the image when the backing file is changed.